# change "width" of "linebreaks" of MathJax on Fly

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

As described [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html), we can use this to configure  how wide the lines of mathematics can be:

```
"HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: "30em" } }
```

Is there a way to change the value of the `width` on fly after that MathJax completed typsetting of formula in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/dXx6TQI1npU/ov-mEAxaIKkJ), use something like

```
function changeWidth(wide){
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(
    ["Config",MathJax.Hub,{"HTML-CSS": {linebreaks: {width: wide+"em"}}}],
    ["Rerender",MathJax.Hub]
  );
}
```

Comment: Why when I change the `["Rerender",MathJax.Hub]` to `["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]`, I cannot see any changes?

Comment: Because `typeset` only looks for new content.